# Validating first names and last names in PHP to store in OpenLDAP

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, ldap

Hi I am trying to validate some user input and I'm not sure what is the correct way to go about it.

I want to validate first name and last name fields for a user creation form. I am using PHP with the Zend framework so I will be writing a validator. After doing some research I think I should really be allowing all UTF8 characters, with no spaces at beginning or end. I'm not sure on the regex but I can find that out later, I will most likely be using php's preg_match.

I'm storing these details in OpenLDAP using the sn field for surname and the givenName for firstname. How should I be restricting the names? Is there a limit to the length in OpenLDAP, do I need to check the characters it accepts or does it accept all characters?

Should I even validate the first name and last name or should I just let the user input what they want?

I am using a separate field for username which will consist of "text.text", text being A-Za-z chars.

I'm not posting code as I just a need a bit of guidance, not really sure whats the best practice here.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? Validating a name and-or last name is pretty hard with only a-z. What if I have combined last name like Jeff-Jefferson? Or William the 4th ?

Comment: Or look at these examples: [link](http://www.neatorama.com/2008/05/19/10-strangest-names-evar/)

Comment: No i'm only validating the username with a-z. This is what I am asking though, I've read that I should just allow all UTF8 chars for firstname and lastname, but I am concerned about what OpenLDAP can handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validating names is a bad idea. There are no universal rules for what is allowed in a name, especially when you want to allow non-western text as well.

This presents a challenge when it comes to LDAP, since there is no guarantee that the directory will understand the charset of the user input. There is an easy solution to this though: `base64_encode()` the values before storing them in LDAP, and `base64_decode()` them on the way out.

Comment: Thankyou that sounds like a good idea, what about length? I can't seem to find the limits for name fields in OpenLDAP

Comment: The is no set length, it would depend on the schema. I would imagine that the length will be adequate though - how much control do you have over the LDAP server?

Comment: Well I've got dev access. I can see that sn and givenNames have a superType of name. name seems to have a syntax property with a length attribute which is set to 32768. Is that the length of the string it can hold? Going back to the validation, it seems I would have to much toO change using base_64_encode as the the software is already live, I think my best bet would be to just check that the names are UTF8 compliant?

Comment: If you can't change the code, you should be able to store any character in any format if you make sure that name type is [a DirectoryString or an OctetString](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/apa/types.html#strings) (DirectoryString would be best). I would imagine the length will be a *byte* length, and UTF-8 characters can be up to 4 bytes. But realistically 32768 still gives you 8192 characters of 4 bytes each, and you won't ever get that because by the time you get up to the 4 byte sequences you getting into characters from dead languages and bizarre punctuation/non printable characters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to validate the names. The directory server schema specifies the syntax of all attributes, including `givenName`, and `sn`. The server will properly encode any names that are presented. If a `DirectoryString` value begins or ends with a space, the server will base64 encode the value for storage.

Though there is a practical limit, LDAP clients should not assume that servers have the capability of enforcing the non-zero length of an attribute value. Some attributes syntaxes are defined to be *non-zero* in length (such as `DirectoryString`), but no upper limit is defined, therefore, clients should not assume the server enforces an upper limit.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Syntaxes and Matching Rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517.html)

Comment: So basically you're saying I don't need to care about character sets nor length?

Comment: The LDAP client should not assume the server enforces attribute length except in cases where the attribute syntax indicates that the length must be non-zero. As to the character set, the client should be aware that attributes have syntax, and that the server enforces that syntax. For example, uidNumber is of 'Integer' syntax, and the server will not accept 'abc' as a value for uidNumber.